# Implementing MiniMax Algorithm in Tic Tac Toe for C

Tags: c, algorithm, minimax

I'm trying to make an unbeatable AI for a tic tac toe game, much like the one at http://perfecttictactoe.herokuapp.com/. However, since I'm still learning C, its a bit simpler as the user always goes first and there's no GUI, and ASCII art is used for the graphics instead. I've looked over various implementations of the MiniMax algorithm, as it seems to be the most recommended way to solve the problem, according to this site as well as many others. I'm having a bit of a problem, as the algorithm does not seem to be working. Instead, it steadily moves left to right beginning in the square (1,1) ([0,0] in the array) and going down to the next row once it reaches the end of the row. I've tried a lot of things, from meticulously combing over my code to rewriting it from scratch, but nothing seems to work. I'm hoping the wonderful community here can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void print(char board[3][3]);
char didwin(char board[3][3]);
void AImove(char board[3][3], int *rows, int *columns);
int MinMax(char board[3][3], int player);

int main(void)
{
    int i, i2, player, rows=0,columns=0;
    char board[3][3], tempboard[3][3], winner;
    string name;
    printf("The computer will now play tic-tac-tow with you.\n");
    printf("The computer will use \"O\" and you will use \"X\".\n");
    printf("You will go first. To begin, please enter your name: ");
    name=GetLine();
    while(true) 
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
        {
            for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++) 
            {
                board[i][i2]='\0';
            }
        }
        print(board);
        for(i=0;i<9&&winner==0;i++)
        { 
            printf("\n");
            player=i%2+1;
            if(player==1)
            {
                printf("\n%s, what row is your square in?\t", name);
                rows=GetInteger()-1;
                printf("\n%s, what column is your square in?\t", name);
                columns=GetInteger()-1;
            }
            else if(player==2)
            {
                printf("\nThe computer will move now.\n");
                for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++)
                    {
                        tempboard[i][i2]=board[i][i2];
                    }
                }
                AImove(tempboard, &rows, &columns);
            }
            if(rows<0||rows>3||columns<0||columns>3||board[rows][columns]=='X'||board[rows][columns]=='O')
            {
                if(player==1)
                {
                    printf("The space is already taken or out of bounds, please try again");    
                }
                i--;
            }
            else 
            {
                if(player==1) board[rows][columns]='X';
                else board[rows][columns]='O';
                print(board);
            }
            winner = didwin(board);
        }
        if(winner!='\0') 
        {
            if(winner=='X') printf("\n\nYou won!");
            else printf("\n\nThe computer won! Try harder next time.");
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("No winner this round. Try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void print(char board[3][3])
{
    int i,i2;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++)
        {
            if(board[i][i2]=='\0')
            {
                printf("   ");
            }   
            else
            {
                printf(" %c ", board[i][i2]);
            }
            if(i2<2) printf("|"); 
        }
        if(i<2)
        {
            printf("\n-----------\n");
        }
    }
}

char didwin(char board[3][3])
{
    int i,i2;
    char temp;
    char winner = '\0';

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        temp=board[i][0];
        for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++) 
        {
            if(board[i][i2]!=temp)
            {
                temp='\0';
            }
        }
        if(temp!='\0') 
        {
            winner=temp;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        temp=board[0][i];
        for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++) 
        {
            if(board[i2][i]!=temp) 
            {
                temp='\0';
            }       
        }
        if(temp!='\0') 
        {
            winner=temp;
        }
    }

    temp=board[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        if(board[i][i]!=temp) 
        {
            temp='\0';
        }
    }
    if(temp!='\0') 
    {
        winner=temp;
    }

    temp=board[0][2];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        if(board[i][2-i]!= temp) 
        {
            temp='\0';
        }
    }
    if(temp!='\0') 
    {
        winner=temp;
    }
    return winner;
}

void AImove(char tempboard[3][3], int *rows,  int *columns)
{
    int points=-1, temppoints, i, i2;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++)
        {
            if(tempboard[i][i2]=='\0')
            {
                tempboard[i][i2]='O';
                temppoints=MinMax(tempboard, 1);
                if(temppoints>points)
                {
                    points=temppoints;
                    *rows=i;
                    *columns=i2;
                }
                tempboard[i][i2]='\0';
            }
        }
    }
}

int MinMax(char tempboard[3][3], int player)
{
    int winner, points, temppoints, i, i2;
    winner=didwin(tempboard);
    if(winner=='X') return(0);
    else if (winner=='O') return(999);
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(i2=0;i2<3;i2++)
            {
                if(tempboard[i][i2]='\0')
                {
                    if (player==1)
                    {
                        tempboard[i][i2]='X';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempboard[i][i2]='O';
                    }
                    if (player==1)
                    {
                        temppoints=MinMax(tempboard, 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temppoints=MinMax(tempboard, 1);
                    }
                    if(temppoints>points)
                    {
                        points=temppoints;
                    }
                    tempboard[i][i2]='\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(points);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does assignment rather than comparison in `MinMax()`.  With `points` not initialized and returned, nothing but UB.

```
int points
...
// if(tempboard[i][i2]='\0') { // never true
if (tempboard[i][i2] == '\0') { 
  points == ...
...
return points;
```

BTW: suggest explicitly returning a value from `main()`

Comment: I think he is just down-voting you for no apparent reason; as with the other folk above who replied...! :D

Comment: @jtimz  One gets lots of up-votes with no commented reasons as well as some down votes with not comment - that's the way SO is set-up.  Up/down votes with a comment are constructive feedback.  BTW: I do not think OP has the rep points to down-vote.

Comment: Well, then I don't quite understand why someone down-voted you when you said something that is correct... it is honestly, always baffling when something like this happens. (here is an upvote from me though! yey 0!)

Comment: Oh i didn't notice that. However, along with the changes that ACcreator has pointed out below, the program is showing the same problem. Could you clarify what you mean by "explicitly returning a value from main()"?
*Edit: chux is right, i don't have enough rep to up/downvote because i'm new around here.

Comment: "explicitly returning a value from main()" --> Your `int main()` does not return a value.  Suggest adding `return 0;` to the end of the function.  Somewhere deep in C spec, `main()` may be the only function allowed to _not_ return a value - but _that_ is another question.  Back to the real issue - `mainmax()`. After you fix the `=` vs. `==` problem, you may see additional `minmax()` algorithm application issues - just wanted to get you off this one stumbling block.  The coding fun is in the chase.

Answer (score 0):

The key error of your code is that the algorithm "MinMax" has not been implemented right. Note that based on your evaluation, player1 is the Min player who is trying to make his points as low as possible while player2 is the Max player who is trying to make his points as high as possible. So you should discuss these two cases respectively as follows:

```
if (player==1)
{
    temppoints=MinMax(tempboard, 2);
}
else
{
    temppoints=MinMax(tempboard, 1);
}
if(player==1 && temppoints<points) //HERE
{
    points=temppoints;
}
else if(player==2 && temppoints>points) //HERE
{                                       //HERE
    points=temppoints;                  //HERE
}                                       //HERE
```

Besides the above error, you may also pay attention to some inadvertent errors such as changing `if(tempboard[i][i2]='\0')` to `if(tempboard[i][i2]=='\0')` in the MinMax function.